# Row height change makes columns unreadable

Tags: excel, word-wrap, row-height, vba

I need to display the first line of each row (column(F) in this case) in a readable format in order ensure I am working on the correct row.

The image below shows what happens when I change the row height.  In this case the post_content column becomes unreadable.  I have other columns with the same issue.

The data is read from other workbooks and sheets through VBA.

I have tried the statement below without any affect:

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").WrapText = True

I have been searching on "word Wrap" and "Row Height" and cannot find a solution.

Your input is very welcome, Thanks, CraigM

[image: Unreadable because of a row height change.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the cell content is middle-aligned in the vertical direction. In addition to wrapping the text in the cell, set it to be top-aligned

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
End With
```

You can find the command in the Alignment group of the Home ribbon and use the macro recorder to see what code it requires:

[image]

Comment: Perfect right on the money!  Thank you so very much!  I learned today, CraigM